# Pass string from C# to Rust using FFI

Tags: c#, rust, ffi

I try to pass a `string` as a function argument to a Rust library (`cdylib`) as described in the [Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_arguments/).

I tried to however omit the `libc` dependency, because I think it should not be necessary anymore.
I am using Rust `1.50.0` and .net `5.0.103`.

From the the documentation it seems to me as if the `CStr::from_ptr()` function constructs a `CStr` from the pointer by reading all bytes until the *null-termination*. And that C# strings are automatically marshalled to C compatible strings (and are therefore null-terminated). My problem however is, that I do not get the full string that I supply as the function argument, instead I only get the first character as the string.

This is my `lib.rs`:

```rust
use std::os::raw::c_char;
use std::ffi::CStr;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn print_string(text_pointer: *const c_char) {
    unsafe {
        let text: String = CStr::from_ptr(text_pointer).to_str().expect("Can not read string argument.").to_string();
        println!("{}", text);
    }
}
```

and my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "mylib"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["FrankenApps"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

And this is my C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace dotnet
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("mylib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern void print_string(string text);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            print_string("Hello World.");
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the output when I run the program is:

```
H
```

When I run the linked sample, I get an error:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 1, error_len: Some(1) }', src\lib.rs:12:32
```

However when I only use ASCII characters and modify the code like that:

Rust:

```rust
use libc::c_char;
use std::ffi::CStr;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn how_many_characters(s: *const c_char) -> u32 {
    let c_str = unsafe {
        assert!(!s.is_null());

        CStr::from_ptr(s)
    };

    let r_str = c_str.to_str().unwrap();
    println!("{}", r_str.to_string());
    r_str.chars().count() as u32
}
```

C#

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class StringArguments
{
    [DllImport("mylib", EntryPoint="how_many_characters")]
    public static extern uint HowManyCharacters(string s);

    static public void Main()
    {
        var count = StringArguments.HowManyCharacters("Hello World.");
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```

I do get the desired output:

```
Hello World.
12
```

My question is what did I do wrong in my own sample, where I tried to not use `libc`? Is there any difference between `c_char` in libc and the standard library, that makes them behave differently?

My guess is that I missed something simple, because I do expect this to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since .NET 4.7 you can use `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)` so the following should work fine:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace dotnet
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("mylib.dll")]
        public static extern void print_string([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string utf8Text);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            print_string("göes to élevên");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better, less complexity

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`CharSet = CharSet.Ansi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset?view=net-5.0#fields) which does seem to be the default.

When I replace

```cs
[DllImport("mylib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
```

with

```cs
[DllImport("mylib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
```

I do get the output:

```
Hello World.
```

Still it would have been nice, if unicode strings could be supported somehow.

### Edit

I figured out how to use UTF-8 strings. I did not change anything in the rust implementation, but instead of Marshalling the `string` automatically in C#, a UTF-8 encoded byte array is used as the function parameter in C# like that:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace dotnet
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("mylib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern void print_string(byte[] utf8Text);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            print_string(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("göes to élevên"));
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly and prints:

```
göes to élevên
```

Comment: unicode can't be supported cause quick & dirty OS confuse unicode and UTF-16. Rust std string only support UTF-8. I guess there is some crate that can handle this. maybe https://lib.rs/crates/widestring

Comment: UTF-8 would be sufficient for my use case. I initially thought, that is what `OsString` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html) is for, but I've never got this to work.

Comment: I suggest remove ```CharSet = CharSet.Unicode``` and ```SetLastError = true```. Works fine.

Comment: Should this byte array not be null terminated? `print_string(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("göes to élevên" + '\0'));`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is because you define `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`.

From the documentation when setting `CharSet` to `Unicode` the string is pinned and used directly by the native code. Hence the underlying C# string without null termination is used.
Since a null termination is expected it fails.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-for-strings#strings-used-in-platform-invoke

Just remove `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` and it will work.